# Select specific columns, along with the rest but with certain sequence and group by

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I need your help.

Here I have some tables:

1. Location table : ID, Code, LocationName
2. Room table : ID, IDLocation, RoomNo
3. Assignment table : ID, IDLocation, RoomNo, AssignDate, AssignMonth, AssignYear, ItemA, ItemB, ItemC, .... (the item columns will always increase/indefinite number of item columns)

I'd like to have a select statement with this sequence of order:

***Assignment.ID, Location.LocationName, Assignment.AssignDate, Room.RoomNo, and the rest of the item columns grouped by Assignment.IDLocation***

I came up with this query before:

```
SELECT Assignment.ID, Location.LocationName, Assignment.AssignDate, Room.RoomNo, *
FROM Location, Room, Assignment 
WHERE Assignment.IDLocation=Location.ID 
    AND Assignment.HouseNo=Room.ID 
Group By Assignment.IDLocation
```

However I got this warning instead : "***Cannot group on fields selected with '*'***"

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this query?

Comment: no this is a query I use in a class project... :(

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the columns to be group in your query and don't use "*" to select the other columns.

```
SELECT Assignment.ID, Location.LocationName, Assignment.AssignDate, Room.RoomNo,coulmn1,etch..
FROM Location, Room, Assignment 
WHERE Assignment.IDLocation=Location.ID 
    AND Assignment.HouseNo=Room.ID 
Group By Assignment.IDLocation,Assignment.AssignDate, Room.RoomNo,Column1
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer BizApps, but the item columns will always increase so I couldn't specify them one by one...

Comment: It's kind a difficult..you really need to update you query everytime a column was created. Why is it columns increase?

Comment: Yeah... :( its so troublesome. They might assign a new item into the house, and save the amount of that item into the database. I'm so confused... Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, I guess you have only two options:

- If the SQL is generated on-the-fly, you must iterate through the fields used for the `SELECT` and place them in a variable that you also use for your `GROUP BY`.
- If the SQL is not generated, you will have to find some way to modify it whenever the field list changes.

That said, having a field list that always increases doesn't sound healthy in the long run - you might want to take a look at your design and see if everything is as it should be.

Comment: Well... I guess I should find another way now... :(
Thanks a lot for your suggestion Anders! :)

Comment: You're welcome - from your answer to @BizApps above, it sounds like you need to do some normalization of the table where you store your items.